# Broken Rails references when macOS x is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-4

Today, I update my macOS x to Mavericks, and my projects on rails doesn't works.
when I run my project with the command

> rails server

display me the follow error:

> /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require':
>   dlopen(/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/digest/sha1.bundle,
>   9): Library not loaded:
>   /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
>
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/digest/sha1.bundle
>   Reason: image not found -
>   /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/digest/sha1.bundle
>     from
>   /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:153:in`
>   definition'  from
>   /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:116:in
>   `setup'   from
>   /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/Vincubo/vincubo/config/boot.rb:4:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from bin/rails:7:in`require_relative'  from
>   bin/rails:7:in `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on what version of OSX you upgraded from.

But basically, you should reinstall the ruby version using rvm

Comment: You also will probably need to reinstall any gems that use native compilation (e.g. nokogiri)